# Move Sprite Node While Rotating

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to move a sprite node (a frisbee) in Swift while rotating it. The object moves as expected, but does not rotate. I grouped the two actions together to run in parallel, but it still does not rotate. If I run both actions by themselves they work, but not in parallel. Here is the code:

```
        //spin frisbee
        let oneRevolution = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, duration: 0.5)
        let repeatRotation = SKAction.repeatForever(oneRevolution)



        //move frisbee in an arc

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 3200, y: 1500), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 2000 ))
        let moveFrisbee = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, duration: 1.3)


        let group = SKAction.group([repeatRotation, moveFrisbee])
        let frisbeeSequence = SKAction.sequence([frisbeeSound, group])
        frisbee.run(frisbeeSequence)
```

Comment: Is it possible that the frisbeeSound is blocking you?

Comment: I wouldn't think so since my firsbee moves but it does not rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me about 22 minutes to realize this, but the SKAction.follow function automatically sets the zRotation to rotate relative to the path it follows. I disabled it by changing the "let moveFrisbee" line of code to this:

```
let moveFrisbee = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: false, duration: 1.3)
```